# Call another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

I'm trying to call another view controller in a method of my first view controller.
The view controller I'm trying to call contains a container that embeds a page view controller. Is has the storyboard ID "containerID".

I try it that way:

```
class loadingViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containerID") as ViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

And I get the error, :"whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

But I don't understand why.
Could please someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to present a view controller from a view controller who is not yet on screen. Moving this to `viewDidAppear` should work.

See this duplicate question:
[How to fix the warning: view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659526/how-to-fix-the-warning-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)